# Having a unique record with flag values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

```
SERIAL_NUMBER | BIP_WIDE_AREA_PORT | IP_FAST_REROUTE | GWIP_MULTICAST
_____________________________________________________________________
N7608760           YES                 NO                 NO
N7608760           NO                  YES                NO
```

The table snippet above has four columns serial_number, BIP_WIDE_AREA_PORT, IP_FAST_REROUTE, GWIP_MULTICAST

As such I have a list of serial numbers and to showcase the associated products I have created flags i.e. BIP_WIDE_AREA_PORT, IP_FAST_REROUTE etc.  I want to showcase all the product information in one record. For example, in here: For service_number = N2039163R - I would like to have one row showing information on all the flags rather than two/more records like this:

```
SERIAL_NUMBER | BIP_WIDE_AREA_PORT | IP_FAST_REROUTE | GWIP_MULTICAST
_____________________________________________________________________
N7608760           YES                 YES                NO
```

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this? I am not very familiar with PIVOT function, I have tried it but its not working.

I am writing my case statements as simple as it can be:

```
CASE 
    WHEN P1.name LIKE '%BIP WIDE AREA PORT%' THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'No' 
END AS BIP_WIDE_AREA_PORT,
CASE 
    WHEN P1.name LIKE 'NEXTG BACKUP' THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'No' 
END AS NEXTG_BACKUP
```

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Comment: [DO NOT use images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question.

Comment: Hi @Nick - I have never posted here so thanks for the suggestion. I have edited the text

Comment: Thanks @AmitMohanty. Do you mind taking a look now

Comment: The database design is wrong. How come you have both yes and no associated with BIP_WIDE_AREA_PORT property of one product? I would rather store attributes in a separate table.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `GROUP BY` and `MAX()` :

Because 'Y' > 'N', `YES` will be the maximum when compared to `NO`.

```
SELECT SERIAL_NUMBER, MAX(BIP_WIDE_AREA_PORT) AS BIP_WIDE_AREA_PORT,
                      MAX(IP_FAST_REROUTE) AS IP_FAST_REROUTE,
                      MAX(GWIP_MULTICAST) AS GWIP_MULTICAST
FROM mytable
GROUP BY SERIAL_NUMBER;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/IScZkGAA)

Comment: Too fast for me! :)

Comment: Just one word of warning, I'm not sure if there are collations where Y < N, but there could be some out there. If this need to support weird collations, using that simple lexical ordering might not be enough.